# Given the 300k words -> find all words with given letters present (in any order)? Any Data structure for this?

Tags: data-structures

Does anyone know of the data structure/algorithm for this use case?
Given 300k words, -> find all words with some letters present (letters could be in any order)?

For example find all words with letters a,a,d? (so for example "academics" and "captained" are some of the matches)

I initially looked into GADDAG, but it's not really a good fit here as gaddag is designed more for use cases with sequential substrings.

Comment: As @D.W. says, there's unlikely to be a really good solution.  It would help if you explained what your use case is?  What is expected input?

Comment: What are your constraints? Most of the words are short, so you can just directly store them as an answer for all their subsets of letters. You can handle large words separately.

Comment: @PålGD use case is letting people explore the dictionary dictionary and solving problems like wordle for example

Comment: @Dmitry we the input can change, what if someone searches for t,t,g,f and someon for u,y,o,l,d,s -> you simply cannot generate and store all of those lists -> you'll run out of memory

Comment: That's exactly why I am asking "What are your constraints?". E.g. assume that all words are of length at most 10. Then the total memory required is at most  $10 \cdot 2^{10} \cdot 3\cdot 10^5$. which is few GBs, and in fact much less.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with D.W. that there likely isn't a good general solution, and as long as we don't know exactly what the expected sequence of input is, and how the dictionary looks like, it's hard to give good answers.

I would (for lack of better information) simply cache all possible combinations of queries.  Say that the user input is always three letters, then I would go through the dictionary and simply map every possible collection of three letters to the respective words:

```python
S = collections.defaultdict(set)
for word in dictionary:
  for comb in itertools.combinations(word, 3):
    S["".join(sorted(comb))].add(word)
```

Now, a query is simply:

```python
query = input("Enter query (three letters): ")
print(S[''.join(sorted(query))])
```

Attached below is a small program that I wrote, just for fun.

Usage:

```
(e39) [~]$ python query.py /etc/dictionaries-common/words 
19969 combinations cached
Enter string (Q or ctrl-d for exit): kebx
jukebox
textbook
2 words matched bekx
```

```
Enter string (Q or ctrl-d for exit): aabcd
abdicate
bacardi
backdate
backhand
backward
backyard
balanced
cambodia
carlsbad
drawback
hardback
scabbard
12 words matched aabcd
```

You can also find the most esoteric words (for some definition):

- buzzword
- flapjack
- jacquard
- jaxartes
- jukebox
- qiqihar
- squawked
- vanquish
- zyuganov

```python
import sys
from itertools import combinations as choose
from collections import defaultdict as D


def add_choose(S, word, k):
    choose_k = ["".join(sorted(w)) for w in choose(word, k)]
    for w in choose_k:
        S[w].add(word)


ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"


def isalpha(w):
    for c in w:
        if c not in ALPHABET:
            return False
    return True


def read_file_to_cache(fname):
    S = D(set)
    with open(fname, "r") as fin:
        for l in fin:
            word = l.strip().lower()
            if isalpha(word) and 3 <= len(word) <= 8:
                for i in range(1, 6 + 1):
                    add_choose(S, word, i)
    return S


def run(S):
    while True:
        q = input("Enter string (Q or ctrl-d for exit): ")
        if q == "Q":
            break
        q = "".join(sorted(q.strip().lower()))
        res = sorted(S[q])
        print("\n".join(res))
        print(f"{len(res)} words matched {q}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) != 2:
        exit("Usage python query.py dictionary_file")

    S = read_file_to_cache(sys.argv[1])
    print(f"{len(S)} combinations cached")
    run(S)
```

Comment: Only `assesses` has five of the same letters.  This is quite entertaining.

Answer (score 0):

There's unlikely to be any really good solution, but here is an approach.

For each word in your dictionary, sort the letters in alphabetic order.  For instance, "smile" becomes "eilms" and "honolulu" becomes "hllnoouu".  Store these words in a trie.

Next, given a query (a set of required letters), you can traverse this trie in any order (say, depth-first), pruning the traversal at any node that fails to contain one of the required letters.

The effectiveness of this is likely to depend on the distribution of queries you get.  There are many other approaches possible, and to optimize to the greatest extent possible, we'd probably need to know some information about the expected workload (typical number of required letters, any structure in the queries or are they basically random, etc.).

Comment: I don't understand how this solves the problem.  How do you find all words that contain the letter `x` using the trie?

Comment: @PålGD, To find all words that contain the letter `d`, traverse the trie recursively, but when you reach a node for any letter after `d`, if you haven't already visited the letter `d` (in the path from the root to the current node), don't recurse into any of the children of the current node.